# Map/Reduce over sharded data with RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm having trouble getting a map reduce sample to work when the data is sharded across two nodes.  I'm storing documents that relate to application errors being logged on two local ravenDB nodes, the error documents look like:

Example of document on node 1, there are 6 total

```
errors/1/6
{
  "UniqueId": "c62c7e30-8ec7-45af-88e4-da023d796727",
  "ApplicationName": "MyAppName"
}
```

Example of document on node 2, there are 7 total

```
errors/2/6  --Error stored on shard node 2
{
  "UniqueId": "7e0b0f87-9d75-4e70-9fa0-d64a18bc88dc",
  "ApplicationName": "MyAppName"
}
```

when I run this query:

```
public class ApplicationNames : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ErrorDocument, Application>
{
    public ApplicationNames()
    {
         Map = errors => from error in errors
                        select new { error.ApplicationName, Count = 1 };

        Reduce = results => from error in results
                            group error by new { error.ApplicationName, error.Count } into g
                            select new { g.Key.ApplicationName, Count = g.Sum(x=> x.Count) };
    }
}
```

I'm getting back 2 results; one with a Count of 6, the second with a Count of 7.  I was expecting that the two results from each shard would be combined into one result with a count of 13.  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if that's not how its supposed to work.  I followed the example at http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-sharding to set up the sharding strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Grant,
RavenDB currently doesn't handle reduce over multiple nodes.
You can do that yourself using:

```
session.Query<Application, ApplicationNames>()
   .ToList()
   .Select(new ApplicationNames().Reduce)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: late reply, but since the Reduce property is protected the compiler is complaining with this solution.

Comment: in regard to Reduce being protected, I also tried to create a 'new' Reduce property on my ApplicationNames Index but this would need to be defined with anonymous types to match, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: I am very surprised by this answer, why isn't reduce supported on shards - and when will this feature be implemented?

Comment: Is there a better answer now?  Or is this still the case?